# Is a vaccination certificate from India valid in Germany?

Tags: germany, covid-19

I will be moving to Germany from India in September on blue card visa. I'm fully vaccinated with [AstraZeneca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford%E2%80%93AstraZeneca_COVID-19_vaccine) vaccine.

It is sold under the brand name Covishield in India and that's why it is mentioned only as Covishield on my vaccination certificate.

Even though Covishield is completely approved to enter Germany, I wanted to know if I will be allowed to move freely in Germany with my Indian certificate?

Comment: Did they accept? Could you post an answer if you have one?